# is it possible to open Microsoft Team send message to user or channel from an iOS application?

Tags: ios, microsoft-teams

I want to achieve functionality to send message or create a channel from multiple emails on teams from iOS application.

I tried using

```
MSTeams:/l/chat/0/0?users={email}&message=HelloWorld
```

however this operation seems not working it opens team app chat towards mail but getting error message

[image]

Comment: You need to specify both parties in the chat by email, separated by a ,

Comment: "msteams:/l/chat/0/0?users={email1},{email2}". <- tried this but same result :( @Paulw11

Comment: `msteams:/l/chat/0/0?users=user1@domain.com,user2@domain.com&topicName=Prep%20For%20Meeting%20Tomorrow&message=Hi%20folks%2C%20kicking%20off%20a%20chat%20about%20our%20meeting%20tomorrow` worked for me

Comment: Please have look into this doc-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links?tabs=teamsjs-v2#navigate-to-a-chat

Comment: as per my observation if current account are not a part of any organisation then this links will not work.